# PHP Function/Libiary for checkin is there string with number

Tags: php, search

I want to check is long string contains an element from samples, I mean
I have a long string

```
Lorem ipsum dolor 123 SAMPLE sit amet, consectetur.
```

and in config i have

```
$samples = array("# SAMPLE","SAMPLE #")
```

and function should return that on position `19` there is `123 SAMPLE` from `# SAMPLE`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use preg_match http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php to query "Lorem ipsum...".
To find your special regex use https://regexr.com/ to try and learn ;)
Sthg. like `/[0-9].SAMPLE/g`